# Vue: how to navigate to specific user's profile

Tags: vue.js

i have code below and i want to navigate the user's profile when click on the name after asked by, i tried code below but it's not working and my json file structured as below
**

### questions:Array[10] 0:Object category:"General Knowledge" user:"Saffron" difficulty:"medium" incorrect_answers:Array[3] 0:"Cinnamon" 1:"Cardamom" 2:"Vanilla" question:"What is the world's most expensive spice by weight?" type:"multiple"

**

```html
<template>

<div class="container" width=800px>

  <b-row>
  <b-col cols="8">
  <h1> Recently Asked </h1>


     <ul class="container-question" v-for="(question1,index) in questions" :key="index"  
  >
     <li v-if="answered" >
     {{question1.question.selectedAnswer[index]}}
   <li v-else >
     {{question1.question}}
  <b-row id="asked-info">
  <p>Asked by:  </p>
 
<div 
  id="user" 
  v-for="(answer, index) in answers(question1)"
  :key="index"
> 
<router-link to='/profile'> {{ answer }} </router-link>
 
 
      </div>
 
  </b-row>
  <b-row>
   <div class="category" v-for="(category,index) in category(question1)" :key="index" @click="selectedAnswer(index)">
      <mark> {{ category }} </mark>
       </div> 

       <b-button class="outline-primary" style="margin:auto;">Answer</b-button>
  </b-row>
     </li></ul>

  </b-col>
  <b-col>
  <div class="ask-button">
            <b-button href="#" class="primary">Ask Question</b-button>
        </div>

   
        <div>
  <b-card
    title="Card Title"
   
    style="max-width: 20rem;"
    class="mb-2"
  >
    <b-card-text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
    </b-card-text>

    
  </b-card>
</div>
<div>
  <b-card
    title="Card Title"
   
    style="max-width: 20rem;"
    class="mb-2"
  >
    <b-card-text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
    </b-card-text>

  
  </b-card>
</div>
  </b-col>

  </b-row>
<router-view />

 </div>

   
</template>
<script>
export default {

  
    data(){
    return{
      questions: [],
       answered: null,
      index: 0,
     selectedIndex: null,
     
     
    }
  },

 watch: {
    question1: {
      

      handler() {
        this.selectedIndex = null;
        this.answered = false;
       
      },
    },
  },
methods: {
  answers(question1) {
    let answers = [question1.correct_answer]; 
    return answers;
  },
  

 category(question1){
      let category = [...question1.incorrect_answers];
      return category
    },
      selectedAnswer(index) {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
      this.answered = true;
    },


//   filteredCategory(question1){
//     return (question1.filter((question) => question.incorrect_answers == "Kfc"));
   
  
// },
},


  mounted: function(){
fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple',{
  method: 'get'
})
.then((response) => {
  return response.json()
})
.then((jsonData) => {
  this.questions = jsonData.results
})
  }

}


    

</script>
```

routes.js

```js
import question from './views/question.vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import Register from '@/components/Register'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Logout from '@/components/Logout'
import profile from '@/components/profile'
import contactus from '@/views/contactus'




export const routes = [
  
  { path: "/question", component: question },
  
  { path: "/", component: App },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Register',
    component: Register
  },
  {
    path: '/logout',
    name: 'Logout',
    component: Logout
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'profile',
    component: profile
  },
  {
    path: '/contactus',
    name: 'contactus',
    component: contactus
  },



]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I want to point out here, you don't have to implement all of these, but understand what you are doing wrong:

- You are missing the `<router-view>` tag, which is where you want your component to render because you use `<router-link>`
- `params` are ignored if a `path` is provided. Instead, you need to provide the name of the route or manually specify the whole path with any parameter. Here for your reference: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html
- if you don't `v-bind` your property `to`, it will treat the value as a string. So you want to go like this `<router-link :to="yourLink" />`

In your case, you want to use `<router-link :to="" />` with a dynamic string. There are 2 ways to achieve this: Declarative (`<router-link>`) and Programmatic (`router.push`)

1. Declarative:

`<router-link>` is like an anchor tag, so you should return a string.

```
<router-link :to="yourLink"> {{ userr }} </router-link>

computed: {
    yourLink() {
        return `/profile/${user(question1)}`
    }
}
```

2. Programmatic

When you do a `router.push`, you are not doing a “link” anymore. It’s just a `click` event at that point. So change your `router-link` to a `button` with a `click` event

```
<button @click="yourLink"> {{ userr }} </button>

methods: {
    yourLink() {
        this.$router.push({name:'yourComponentName'} ,params:{user(question1)}})
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In your `router.js`:

```
{
    path:'/profile/:user',
    name: 'profile,
    component: profile,
    props: true
}
```

In your `router-link`:

```
<router-link :to="`/profile/${user(question1)}`"> {{ userr }} </router-link>
```

Then in your `profile.vue`, you can query the params by `this.$route.params.user`, for example, if you want to output it in a `<p>` tag:

```
<p>{{ this.$route.params.user }}</p>
```

Comment: i tried your answer, programmatic way is changing the url but it's not directing me to /profile that i specified in component name , however in profile side i tried to recieve the params i sent for example welcome user1 following same thing but also didn't work

Comment: Have you included the tag `<router-view>` in your template as well?

Comment: Could you share your current codes, what you have so far please?

Comment: i updated code above all i want is when direct to profile page it should know which profile id is this inorder to show his profile, idk if i should add something to profile in routes. js file?

Comment: I have updated it in the edit, at the end of my answer

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please upvote it, and if it answers your question, please mark it as accepted

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted. Happy coding! =))